# Quotient Ring of $P_3/\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

(This question originates from Pinter's abstract algebra, Chapter 19 Exercise A2.)

Addition and multiplication are defined as follows.

If $A$ and $B$ are elements of $P_D$
(that is, subsets of $D$), then

\begin{align*}
    A+B &= (A-B) \cup (B-A) \text{ and } AB = A\cap B
\end{align*}

Let $P_3$ be $P_D$ where $D=\{a,b,c\}$. Let $A=P_3, J=\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}.$

> List the elements of $A/J$, and then write the addition and multiplication tables of $A/J$.

Attempt:

The elements of $A/J$ are the 4 cosets:

1. $J=\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}$
2. $J+\{b\}=\{\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$
3. $J+\{c\}=\{\{c\},\{a,c\}\}$
4. $J+\{b,c\}=\{\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$

Addition table:
\begin{array}{c | c c c c }
        +    & J         & J+\{b\}   & J+\{c\}   & J+\{b,c\} \\ \hline
      J      & J         & J+\{b\}   & J+\{c\}   & J+\{b,c\} \\
     J+\{b\} & J+\{b\}   & J         & J+\{b,c\} & J+\{c\}   \\
     J+\{c\} & J+\{c\}   & J+\{b,c\} & J         & J+\{b\}   \\
   J+\{b,c\} & J+\{b,c\} & J+\{c\}   & J+\{b\}   & J \\
\end{array}

Multiplication table:
\begin{array}{c | c c c c }
 \times    & J   & J+\{b\}   & J+\{c\}   & J+\{b,c\} \\ \hline
 J        & J   & J         & J         & J         \\
J+\{b\}   & J   & J+\{b\}   & J         & J+\{b\}   \\
J+\{c\}   & J   & J         & J+\{c\}   & J+\{c\}   \\
J+\{b,c\} & J   & J+\{b\}   & J+\{c\}   & J+\{b,c\} \\
\end{array}

Do they look right?

Comment: These do look right!